# Share history between react-router v4 with multiple ReactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Need help with sharing history between two ReactDOM.render conmonent. I did it with Redux but no lack with react-router v4.

Code: index.js -> firs ReactDOM.render

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {AppContextProvider} from './context';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import reducerReducer from "./store/reducers/reducer";
import mapReducer from './store/reducers/map';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer: reducerReducer,
    map: mapReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContextProvider>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </AppContextProvider>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Code: Map.js -> second ReactDOM.render

```
const popUpHTML = (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Router history={createBrowserHistory}>
                        <PopUpClick
                            name={name}
                            img={img}
                            id={id}
                        />
                    </Router>
                </Provider>
            );

            const addPopup = (popUpHTML, coordinates) =>  {
                const el = document.createElement('div');
                // el.className = "marker";

                ReactDOM.render(popUpHTML, el);


                const mapboxGlPopup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
                    closeButton: false,
                    offset: 16,
                    anchor: 'top'
                }).setDOMContent(el)
                    .setLngLat(coordinates)
                    .addTo(map);
            }

            addPopup(popUpHTML, coordinates);
```

So I need to get on click same URL history, now i gor just URL replace.
This is my rendered Components, and they are two whole new instance:
[React Component in dev tools.](https://ibb.co/GHXChr0)

Comment: why you need 2 ReactDOMs? Use ReactDOM.createPortal instead

Comment: check this and pick something for yourself: https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md

Comment: @demkovych i need two ReactDOM.render because of mapboxGlPopup.setDOMContent(). I try many combination for get setDOMContent to work, for example .setDOMContent(popUpHTML) trow me error: "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." I have idea just to forward component but it's not work. If you can help me how to fix node error it will be perfect.

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup#setdomcontent
This is what setDOMContent() need 
"Sets the popup's content to the element provided as a DOM node."
I am preaty new to react so i don't know how to forward component as DOM node .

Comment: here is for react: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/

Comment: That only implementation. I impeded and it works perfect. But this is a little bit advance.